# Does anybody know what does " Uncaught ReferenceError: analytics is not defined " mean n why no app user after installation?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-analytics, ionic-framework

I'm using google analytics with my ionic framework app and followed the instruction in https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-google-analytics-ionicframework/, I use mobile app preference in google analytics. First I tested it in my device but I  got no mobile app user in the analytics overview, instead i got users using windows and mac. And in my browser appears "Uncaught ReferenceError: analytics is not defined". I don't know what I've done wrong...

Here's my code :

```
.controller('AnalyticsController', function($scope) {
    if(typeof analytics !== undefined) { analytics.trackView("Analytics Controller"); }

    $scope.initEvent = function() {
        if(typeof analytics !== undefined) { analytics.trackEvent("Category", "Action", "Label", 25); }
    }
})

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(typeof analytics !== undefined) {
            analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-xxxx");
        } else {
            console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: add it to your function maybe, like `function($scope, analytics)`

Answer (score 2):

It means just that, `analytics` has not been defined. The reason that your `if` statements aren't catching it is because `typeof undefined` returns the string `"undefined"` not the primitive `undefined`, so you should do:

```
.controller('AnalyticsController', function($scope) {
    if(typeof analytics !== 'undefined') { analytics.trackView("Analytics Controller"); }

    $scope.initEvent = function() {
        if(typeof analytics !== 'undefined') { analytics.trackEvent("Category", "Action", "Label", 25); }
    }
})

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(typeof analytics !== 'undefined') {
            analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-xxxx");
        } else {
            console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
        }
    });
});
```

Ideally, you should set up a factory to create an injectable analytics service, and not reference things on the global scope.

Comment: the error doesn't show up anymore, thank you. Now it shows up the console.log, is that because i didn't test it in actual device ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. `console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");` is in the else of your conditional, and that should fire if analytics is undefined.

Comment: My question is, do we need to run the app in our smartphone so that google analytics is available ?

Answer (score -1):

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/my-google-analytics-in-my-ionic-app-doesnt-report-any-active-app-user/21073/ <-- best solution for you.